# $facebook->getUser() returning 0 and showing exception

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am doing login and fetching albums from facebook:

1) Here, first of all the function `$facebook->getUser()` returning 0

2) If I commented the rest of code i.e. `if/else` conditions then it going into the catch block and showing exception like :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

3) I found lots of posts on stackoverflow and google regarding to this and tried almost all but still its not working. Thats why I am sharing the code here.

4) Also I created the new app facebook and tried for it but still problem persist.

Following is my code :

```
public function facebookapiAction() {
        require 'auth/src/facebook.php';
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                    'appId' => '3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7',
                    'secret' => '6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5',
                    'cookie' => true,                    
                ));
        return $facebook;
    }

    public function facebookalbumAction() {
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user');
        $facebook = $this->facebookapiAction();
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        $albumid = $this->_getParam('albumid');
        if ($user <> '0' && $user <> '') {
            if ($albumid != "") {
                $photos = $this->albumlistAction($albumid, $facebook);                
            } else {
                try {
                    $albumArrInfo = array();
                    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/albums');                                       
                } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                    error_log($e);
                    exit;
                }
            }
            $session->fb_logout = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/register/logout/id/Logout"));
            $session->isfb = 1;
        } else {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['getfurl']) && !(isset($_REQUEST['state']))) {                
                $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('display' => 'popup','scope' => 'manage_pages,user_events,email,read_stream,user_photos,offline_access'));
                echo $loginUrl;
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

    public function albumlistAction($albumid, $facebook) {
        $photos = $facebook->api("/{$albumid}/photos");
        $albumArr = array();
        $albumArrInfo = array();
        foreach ($photos['data'] as $photo) {
            $albumArr['id'] = $photo['id'];
            $albumArr['name'] = $photo['name'];            
        }        
        return $albumArr;
    }
```

Whats wrong with this code.

Need help.

Comment: Do you sure that there are users give your application the required privileges?

Comment: @Termis : Sorry, but I didn't get you

Comment: It looks like FB is having some problem, I am experiencing this same error message with a code that was working perfectly yesterday...

Comment: @RedDragon : But created new app still it is persist

Comment: After more investigation, I think it may be related to December 5th, 2012 breaking changes: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/09/05/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a similar problem I was facing. Bug report is here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238039849657148

Try updating to the latest version of the PHP-SDK (3.2.2).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
...
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/'.$user.'/albums');
```